# ios smart banner ads by adwhril or mobclix

Tags: ios, iad, adwhirl, mobclix

I am developing a free app in which i have iAds integrated currently. To maximise my earning I wanted to integrate mobclix or adwhril, I want to integrate smart banners like iAds but with both services I couldnt find smart ads option.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [AdMob Mediation](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2413211) instead of AdWhirl.  AdMob Mediation supports all types of ad formats (including smart banner); AdWhirl only supports 320x50 banners.